# overflow:scroll not working with absolutely positioned child div?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout problem with an absolutely positioned child div that contains output text from my input field. I want the wrapper div around it to scroll vertically when the child div reaches its top (the text must fill the wrapper div from the bottom up), but this isn't happening, the scrollbar remains inactivated (and I can't see my "input1" anymore, as you can see in picture 2).

I have created a simple example to show that the child disappears beyond the parent when reaching the top. This is what is happening on screen:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

And my css code is:

```
#wrapperWithScrollbarForOutput {

  background-color: #453750;
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
} 

#outputDivForText {

  background-color: #73648A;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#inputDiv {

  background-color: #9882AC;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 230px;

}
```

And the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Writing from bottom up.</title>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapperWithScrollbarForOutput">
            <div id="outputDivForText"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="inputDiv">
            <input type="text" id="myInput">
            <button onclick="buttonClicked()">Publish</button>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you please add some html code

Comment: From first glance it looks like you're adding the text upwards so it's actually pushing the text off the screen so the scrolling will not take effect.

Comment: I want the "pushing" to happen, at least visually, so that I can add more inputs at the bottom, but I also want to be able to scroll so that I can see the first ones. Do you know of a better method for this that also puts the very first input at the bottom (like in picture 1)?

Comment: give #outputDivForText a max-height and move the overflow-y:auto; to that: https://jsfiddle.net/pbf38mqw/5/

Comment: thanks @Bosc, this gave me the solution (I just added a javascript function to scroll to the bottom when I add a new input). can I accept this as the answer somehow?

Answer (score 0):

update #outputDivForText  css with my css

```
  #wrapperWithScrollbarForOutput {
  background-color: #453750;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }

#outputDivForText {
background-color: #73648A;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
width: 50px;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}

#inputDiv {
  background-color: #9882AC;
}
```

Comment: this actually puts the first input (or the outputDiv to be more precise) at the top of the wrapper, but I want it to start at the bottom (like in picture 1), and I want the scrolling to happen when the first output later reaches the top.

Comment: this second link starts out the right way! But try adding more inputs, when they reach the top of the screen the scrolling still doesn't happen unfortunately..

Comment: i still get no scrolling when I add more inputs. it seems like the parent only starts scrolling when the bottom is reached, not when content extends beyond the top.. for some reason.

Comment: let me know why you use position absolute in #outputDivForText ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141767/discussion-between-eli6-and-suresh-suthar).